# Indigenous land shapefiles for world

Tags: geospatial, global, land

I am not too sure where there are "tribal" or "indigenous" peoples in every part of the world, but what I am thinking about are:

- Native American tribal lands in the United States.
- South American tribes in the Amazon areas.
- Other potentially non-Amazonian South American tribes (not sure about this, but I think I remember learning about Argentinian tribes).
- Australian Aboriginal tribes
- Central/Southern African Bushman tribes.
- Canadian Aboriginal tribes (Inuit/Eskimo are all I barely know of)
- Papua New Guinea (though not sure they have lands)

Those are the only tribal peoples I am somewhat introduced with.

What I would like to see, but am unfamiliar with whether or not tribes (so to speak) exist in these areas, are in these areas:

- Central American tribes (maybe Mayan, Zapotec, Aztec are considered tribal and have lands).
- China/Tibet
- Japan, etc.
- Indonesia
- India, etc.
- Other parts of Africa, etc.
- Papua New Guinea
- Northern Russia/Tundra areas (Caucasians I think, though not sure if they consider themselves tribes with tribal lands).

Basically I am wondering if any data (shapefiles specifically) exist on the lands of these (potentially) tribal/indigenous peoples. I have found a complete map of tribal lands for the United States, but not for the other ones I listed in the first list, nor these potential tribal groups I listed afterwards.

[This](https://www.wri.org/news/2015/11/release-first-interactive-global-map-indigenous-and-community-territories-will-help) looked promising but the link doesn't seem good.

Answer (score 2):

I would start here: http://www.landmarkmap.org/data/#data-6

It has a lot of data for Central America and Africa.

It also lists that data is available by request for:
    India: gpicl@fes.org.in; brajesh@fes.org.in 
    Indonesia:    rumahaman@cbn.net.id

It does not really have data on China, Japan, Papua New Guinea, or Russia.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the overall coverage, but the [Ethnic Power Relations](https://icr.ethz.ch/data/epr/) dataset family contains shapefiles on a wide range of ethnic groups which might be of use to you.